# How to show admin specific data in Laravel Tastyigniter(Online food ordering) system

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel Tastyigniter system in which I want to show the locations name in dropdown in Menus module according to locations added by admin which is currently logged in.
For Example,   If admin A added two locations such as location A and location B and
admin B added two locations such as location C and location D resp.

- Note - The locations are getting saved in database with created_by column which is id of admin adding the location.

A)  What supposed to happen -

- If I logged in as admin A then in location dropdown Location A and Location B should get display
- If I logged in as admin B then in location dropdown Location C and Location D should get display.

B) What is happening currently -

- For both the admins all the 4 locations are getting displayed.

C) Following is the Code -

- Here is Menus_model.php

  ```
  <?php namespace Admin\Models;

   use Admin\Traits\Locationable;
   use Igniter\Flame\Database\Traits\Purgeable;
   class Menus_model extends Model
   {
      use Purgeable;
      use Locationable;

      const LOCATIONABLE_RELATION = 'locations';

      public $relation = [
       'morphToMany' => [
           'locations' => ['Admin\Models\Locations_model', 'name' => 
            'locationable'],
        ],
      ];

      protected $purgeable = ['locations'];     
    }
  ```
- Here is menus_model.php which is present under models->config

  ```
    <?php

       $config['form']['tabs'] = [
      'fields' => [
            'locations' => [
                'label' => 'Location',
                'type' => 'relation',
                'span' => 'right',
                'valueFrom' => 'locations',
                'nameFrom' => 'location_name',
                'locationAware' => 'hide',
              ],
           ],
        ];

       return $config;
  ```

Here is the Locations_model.php file code under models folder

```
   <?php namespace Admin\Models;

    use Admin\Traits\HasDeliveryAreas;
    use Admin\Traits\HasWorkingHours;
    use Igniter\Flame\Database\Attach\HasMedia;
    use Igniter\Flame\Database\Traits\HasPermalink;
    use Igniter\Flame\Database\Traits\Purgeable;
    use Igniter\Flame\Location\Models\AbstractLocation;
    use DB;
    /**
      * Locations Model Class
      *
      * @package Admin
    */
  class Locations_model extends AbstractLocation
    {
      use HasWorkingHours;
      use HasDeliveryAreas;
      use HasPermalink;
      use Purgeable;
      use HasMedia;

      const LOCATION_CONTEXT_SINGLE = 'single';

      const LOCATION_CONTEXT_MULTIPLE = 'multiple';

      protected $appends = ['location_thumb'];

      protected $hidden = ['options'];

      public $casts = [
           'location_country_id' => 'integer',
           'location_lat' => 'double',
           'location_lng' => 'double',
           'offer_delivery' => 'boolean',
           'offer_collection' => 'boolean',
           'delivery_time' => 'integer',
           'collection_time' => 'integer',
           'last_order_time' => 'integer',
           'reservation_time_interval' => 'integer',
           'reservation_stay_time' => 'integer',
           'location_status' => 'boolean',
           'options' => 'serialize',
           'location_city' => 'integer',
           'region_id'=>'integer',
          ];

     public $relation = [
        'hasMany' => [
        'working_hours' => ['Admin\Models\Working_hours_model', 'delete' => 
         TRUE],
        'delivery_areas' => ['Admin\Models\Location_areas_model', 'delete' 
         => TRUE],
        'reviews' => ['Admin\Models\Reviews_model', 'delete' => TRUE],
    ],
    'belongsTo' => [
        'country' => ['System\Models\Countries_model', 'otherKey' => 
        'country_id', 'foreignKey' => 'location_country_id'],
        'city' => ['Admin\Models\City_model', 'otherKey' => 'city_id', 'foreignKey' => 'location_city'],
        'region' => ['Admin\Models\Region_model', 'otherKey' => 'region_id', 'foreignKey' => 'region_id'],
    ],
    'belongsToMany' => [
        'tables' => ['Admin\Models\Tables_model', 'table' => 'location_tables'],
        'cuisines' => ['Admin\Models\Cuisines_model', 'table' => 'location_cuisines'],
        
    ],
];

protected $purgeable = ['tables', 'delivery_areas','cuisines'];

public $permalinkable = [
    'permalink_slug' => [
        'source' => 'location_name',
        'controller' => 'local',
    ],
];

public $mediable = [
    'thumb',
    'gallery' => ['multiple' => TRUE],
];

protected static $allowedSortingColumns = [
    'distance asc', 'distance desc',
    'reviews_count asc', 'reviews_count desc',
    'location_id asc', 'location_id desc',
    'location_name asc', 'location_name desc',
];

public $url;

protected static $defaultLocation;

public static function onboardingIsComplete()
{
    if (!$defaultId = params('default_location_id'))
        return FALSE;

    if (!$model = self::isEnabled()->find($defaultId))
        return FALSE;

    return isset($model->getAddress()['location_lat'])
        AND isset($model->getAddress()['location_lng'])
        AND ($model->hasDelivery() OR $model->hasCollection())
        AND isset($model->options['hours'])
        AND $model->delivery_areas->where('is_default', 1)->count() > 0;
}

public function getWeekDaysOptions()
{
    return ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
}

//
// Events
//

protected function afterFetch()
{
    $this->parseOptionsValue();
}

protected function beforeSave()
{
    $this->parseOptionsValue();
}

protected function afterSave()
{
    $this->performAfterSave();
}

protected function beforeDelete()
{
    Location_tables_model::where('location_id', $this->getKey())->delete();
    Location_cuisines_model::where('location_id', $this->getKey())->delete();
}

//
// Scopes
//

/**
 * Scope a query to only include enabled location
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function scopeIsEnabled($query)
{
    return $query->where('location_status', 1);
}

public function scopeListFrontEnd($query, array $options = [])
{
    extract(array_merge([
        'page' => 1,
        'pageLimit' => 20,
        'sort' => null,
        'search' => null,
        'latitude' => null,
        'longitude' => null,
    ], $options));

    if ($latitude AND $longitude)
        $query->selectDistance($latitude, $longitude);

    $searchableFields = ['location_name', 'location_address_1', 'location_address_2', 'location_city',
        'location_state', 'location_postcode', 'description'];

    if (!is_array($sort)) {
        $sort = [$sort];
    }

    foreach ($sort as $_sort) {
        if (in_array($_sort, self::$allowedSortingColumns)) {
            $parts = explode(' ', $_sort);
            if (count($parts) < 2) {
                array_push($parts, 'desc');
            }
            [$sortField, $sortDirection] = $parts;
            $query->orderBy($sortField, $sortDirection);
        }
    }

    $search = trim($search);
    if (strlen($search)) {
        $query->search($search, $searchableFields);
    }

    return $query->paginate($pageLimit, $page);
}

//
// Accessors & Mutators
//

public function getLocationThumbAttribute()
{
    return $this->hasMedia() ? $this->getThumb() : null;
}

public function getDeliveryTimeAttribute($value)
{
    return (int)$value;
}

public function getCollectionTimeAttribute($value)
{
    return (int)$value;
}

public function getFutureOrdersAttribute($value)
{
    return (bool)$value;
}

public function getReservationTimeIntervalAttribute($value)
{
    return (int)$value;
}

//
// Helpers
//

public function setUrl($suffix = null)
{
    if (is_single_location())
        $suffix = '/menus';

    $this->url = site_url($this->permalink_slug.$suffix);
}

public function hasGallery()
{
    return $this->hasMedia('gallery');
}

public function getGallery()
{
    $gallery = array_get($this->options, 'gallery');
    $gallery['images'] = $this->getMedia('gallery');

    return $gallery;
}

public function parseOptionsValue()
{
    $value = @unserialize($this->attributes['options']) ?: [];

    $this->parseHoursFromOptions($value);

    $this->parseAreasFromOptions($value);

    $this->attributes['options'] = @serialize($value);

    return $value;
}

public function listAvailablePayments()
{
    $result = [];

    $payments = array_get($this->options, 'payments', []);
    $paymentGateways = Payments_model::listPayments();

    foreach ($paymentGateways as $payment) {
        if ($payments AND !in_array($payment->code, $payments)) continue;

        $result[$payment->code] = $payment;
    }

    return collect($result);
}

public function performAfterSave()
{
    $this->restorePurgedValues();

    if (array_key_exists('hours', $this->options)) {
        $this->addOpeningHours($this->options['hours']);
    }

    if (array_key_exists('delivery_areas', $this->attributes)) {
        $this->addLocationAreas($this->attributes['delivery_areas']);
    }

    if (array_key_exists('tables', $this->attributes)) {
        $this->addLocationTables($this->attributes['tables']);
    }
    if (array_key_exists('cuisines', $this->attributes)) {
        $this->addLocationCuisines($this->attributes['cuisines']);
    }
}

public static function getDefault()
{
    if (self::$defaultLocation !== null) {
        return self::$defaultLocation;
    }

    $defaultLocation = self::isEnabled()->where('location_id', params('default_location_id'))->first();
    if (!$defaultLocation) {
        $defaultLocation = self::isEnabled()->first();
        if ($defaultLocation) {
            params('default_location_id', $defaultLocation->getKey());
            params()->save();
        }
    }

    return self::$defaultLocation = $defaultLocation;
}

/**
 * Create a new or update existing location tables
 *
 * @param array $tables
 *
 * @return bool
 */
   public function addLocationTables($tables = [])
   {
      return $this->tables()->sync($tables);
   }
   public function addLocationCuisines($cuisines = [])
   {
      return $this->cuisines()->sync($cuisines);
   }
 }
```

- Here is locations_model.php which is present under models->config folder

  ```
  <?php

    $config['form']['tabs'] = [
      'defaultTab' => 'lang:admin::lang.locations.text_tab_general',
         'fields' => [
          'location_name' => [
            'label' => 'lang:admin::lang.label_name',
            'type' => 'text',
            'span' => 'left',
           ],
          'location_email' => [
          'label' => 'lang:admin::lang.label_email',
          'type' => 'text',
          'span' => 'right',
          ],
       'location_telephone' => [
         'label' => 'lang:admin::lang.locations.label_telephone',
         'type' => 'text',
         'span' => 'left',
       ],
      'location_status' => [
        'label' => 'lang:admin::lang.label_status',
        'type' => 'switch',
        'default' => 1,
        'span' => 'right',
      ],  
      'created_by' => [
        'type' => 'hidden',
        'default' => isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ? $_SESSION['user_id'] : '',
       ],
     ],
   ];

  return $config;
  ```
- **UPDATED**
- Basically I want to diaply locations in menus form , Currently in menus form all the locations are getting display and   the code for this is mentioned below
- This is Menus.php controller

  ```
  <?php namespace Admin\Controllers;

  use Admin\Classes\AdminController;
  use Admin\Models\Menu_options_model;
  use AdminMenu;
  use ApplicationException;

   class Menus extends AdminController
   {
     public $implement = [
      'Admin\Actions\ListController',
      'Admin\Actions\FormController',
      'Admin\Actions\LocationAwareController',
   ];

  public $listConfig = [
    'list' => [
        'model' => 'Admin\Models\Menus_model',
        'title' => 'lang:admin::lang.menus.text_title',
        'emptyMessage' => 'lang:admin::lang.menus.text_empty',
        'defaultSort' => ['menu_id', 'DESC'],
        'configFile' => 'menus_model',
    ],
   ];

  protected $requiredPermissions = 'Admin.Menus';

   public function __construct()
  {  
    parent::__construct();

    AdminMenu::setContext('menus');
   }

  public function edit_onChooseMenuOption($context, $recordId)
  {
    $menuOptionId = post('Menu._options');
    if (!$menuOption = Menu_options_model::find($menuOptionId))
        throw new ApplicationException('Please select a menu option to   
     attach');

    $model = $this->asExtension('FormController')->formFindModelObject($recordId);

    $menuItemOption = $model->menu_options()->create(['option_id' => $menuOptionId]);

    $menuOption->option_values()->get()->each(function ($model) use ($menuItemOption) {
        $menuItemOption->menu_option_values()->create([
            'menu_option_id' => $menuItemOption->menu_option_id,
            'option_value_id' => $model->option_value_id,
            'new_price' => $model->price,
        ]);
    });

    $model->reload();
    $this->asExtension('FormController')->initForm($model, $context);

    flash()->success(sprintf(lang('admin::lang.alert_success'), 'Menu item option attached'))->now();

    $formField = $this->widgets['form']->getField('menu_options');

    return [
        '#notification' => $this->makePartial('flash'),
        '#'.$formField->getId('group') => $this->widgets['form']->renderField($formField, [
            'useContainer' => FALSE,
        ]),
      ];
    }
  }
  ```
- Below is Locaations.php controller

  ```
   <?php namespace Admin\Controllers;

    use Admin\Facades\AdminLocation;
    use Admin\Models\Locations_model;
    use AdminMenu;
    use Exception;
    use Geocoder;

    class Locations extends \Admin\Classes\AdminController
    {
      public $implement = [
           'Admin\Actions\ListController',
          'Admin\Actions\FormController',
       ];

     public $listConfig = [
      'list' => [
        'model' => 'Admin\Models\Locations_model',
        'title' => 'lang:admin::lang.locations.text_title',
        'emptyMessage' => 'lang:admin::lang.locations.text_empty',
        'defaultSort' => ['location_id', 'DESC'],
        'configFile' => 'locations_model',
      ],
   ];


   protected $requiredPermissions = 'Admin.Locations';

   public function __construct()
   {
     parent::__construct();

    AdminMenu::setContext('locations', 'restaurant');
   }

  public function remap($action, $params)
  {
    if ($action != 'settings' AND AdminLocation::check())
        return $this->redirect('locations/settings');

    return parent::remap($action, $params);
  }

  public function settings($context = null)
  { 
    if (!AdminLocation::check())
        return $this->redirect('locations');

    $this->asExtension('FormController')->edit('edit', $this- 
    >getLocationId());
  }

  public function index_onSetDefault($context = null)
   {
    $defaultId = post('default');

    if (Locations_model::updateDefault(['location_id' => $defaultId])) {
        flash()->success(sprintf(lang('admin::lang.alert_success'), 
    lang('admin::lang.locations.alert_set_default')));
    }

    return $this->refreshList('list');
  }

  public function settings_onSave($context = null)
   {
    try {
        $this->asExtension('FormController')->edit_onSave('edit', 
      params('default_location_id'));

        return $this->refresh();
    }
    catch (Exception $ex) {
        $this->handleError($ex);
     }
  }

   public function listOverrideColumnValue($record, $column, $alias = null)
    {
     if ($column->type != 'button')
        return null;

     if ($column->columnName != 'default')
        return null;

    $attributes = $column->attributes;
    $column->iconCssClass = 'fa fa-star-o';
    if ($record->getKey() == params('default_location_id')) {
        $column->iconCssClass = 'fa fa-star';
    }

    return $attributes;
   }

  public function formExtendQuery($query)
  {
    if ($locationId = $this->getLocationId())
        $query->where('location_id', $locationId);
  }

  public function formAfterSave($model)
  {
    if (post('Location.options.auto_lat_lng')) {
        if ($logs = Geocoder::getLogs())
            flash()->error(implode(PHP_EOL, $logs))->important();
     }
    }
  }
  ```

**Views**

- Now the n views folder there is folder names menus and under that folder there is create.php  file  for displaying create  menu form
- The code in views->menus->create.php  file is below

  ```
    <div class="row-fluid">
     <?= form_open(current_url(),
      [
        'id'     => 'edit-form',
        'role'   => 'form',
        'method' => 'POST',
     ]
   ); ?>

    <?= $this->renderForm(); ?>

    <?= form_close(); ?>
  </div>
  ```

**FormController**

- Now the `renderForm()`  function is present at path  app/admin/actions/FormController.php  which we have defined in Locations and  Menus controller under   `public $implement = ['Admin\Actions\FormController'];`
- Ther  `renderForm()`   function is as follow

  ```
    public function renderForm($options = [])
     {
      if (!$this->formWidget) {
        throw new Exception(lang('admin::lang.form.not_ready'));
       }

      if (!is_null($this->toolbarWidget)) {
        $form[] = $this->toolbarWidget->render();
       }

      $form[] = $this->formWidget->render($options);

      return implode(PHP_EOL, $form);
    }
  ```

**Widgets**

- At last the  there are widgets  for input fields  like select, text, radio, checkbox etc. In our case we have  widget name field_selectlist, which is present at path  app/admin/widgets/form/field_selectlist.php
- The field_selectlist.php  file has code as below

  ```
  <?php 
     $fieldOptions = $field->options();
     //print_r($fieldOptions);die; All the locations are displaying here.

     $isCheckboxMode = $field->config['mode'] ?? 'checkbox';
     $selectMultiple = $isCheckboxMode == 'checkbox';
     $checkedValues = (array)$field->value;
     $enableFilter = (count($fieldOptions) > 20);
  ?>
  <div class="control-selectlist">
    <select
    data-control="selectlist"
    id="<?= $field->getId() ?>"
    name="<?= $field->getName() ?><?= $selectMultiple ? '[]' : '' ?>"
    <?php if ($field->placeholder) { ?>data-non-selected-text="<?= 
    e(lang($field->placeholder)) ?>"<?php } ?>
    <?= $selectMultiple ? 'multiple="multiple"' : '' ?>
    data-enable-filtering="<?= $enableFilter; ?>"
    data-enable-case-insensitive-filtering="<?= $enableFilter; ?>"
    <?= $field->getAttributes() ?>>

    <?php if ($field->placeholder) { ?>
        <option value=""><?= e(lang($field->placeholder)) ?></option>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php 

    foreach ($fieldOptions as $value => $option) { ?>
        <?php
        if (!is_array($option)) $option = [$option];
        if ($field->disabled AND !in_array($value, $checkedValues)) continue;
        ?>
        <option
            <?= in_array($value, $checkedValues) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?>
            value="<?= $value ?>">
            <?= e(is_lang_key($option[0]) ? lang($option[0]) : $option[0]) ?>
            <?php if (isset($option[1])) { ?>
                <span><?= e(is_lang_key($option[1]) ? lang($option[1]) : 
              $option[1]) ?></span>
            <?php } ?>
        </option>
    <?php } ?>
  ```

Comment: where is relation between location and admin is there any user id column in location table

Comment: yes I have added note above , there is created_by column in loations table which has id of admin who created it

Comment: so where are you using that created_by column to get locations

Comment: Thats what I am searching for because in this tastyigniter system there is no direct query in model to fetchh records

Comment: actually i can help but i need more code, view template and locations_model

Comment: maybe other file also be requeired to see

Comment: @NurbekBoymurodov, I have updated my answer and mentioned both locations model files present under models folder and  models->config folder respectively.

Comment: look I need controller or any helper file which getting locations and sending it to view file

Comment: @NurbekBoymurodov,  Thank you for your reply. I have updated  the question with views and form controller files